# Is there an alternative to Spatial Join that does not create a new feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I'm looking to write a script for a tool similar to Spatial Join. Where two features intersect, the target layer will have one of its fields updated based off of the same field in the source layer. Spatial Join creates a new feature class with a new field that is populated by the join. I want a tool that just grabs a value from a particular field in fcA, selects the feature(s) in fcB that intersect fcA, and then updates a field in fcB based on the related field in fcA.

My question is, is there another similar tool that I am unaware of? The use case of such a tool would be with a telecom dataset where a line (cable) intersects a point (pole), and then the cable gets the route value from the pole. I want to write this tool but don't want to take the time if there is already one out there. I also don't want a new feature class like is created when using Spatial Join. I'm working with ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Esri's [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/).  It is not part of the Core ArcGIS Desktop, so it needs to be downloaded/installed separately, but it doesn't cost any extra.

With the Attribute Assistant you can create a number of different types of rules that can run manually or automatically, including copying values from point features onto a line (poles onto cables for example).

Look at the [From Junction Field](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#from-junction-field) and the [To Junction Field](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#to-junction-field) methods for a starting point for this.

The Attribute Assistant can take a bit of setting up, but read the documentation - it's very good - and you'll find it's actually not too difficult to get up and running.